# Using Jquery/SetTimeout to Update Div - Update Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

**What I am Trying to Do:**
I am trying to use settimeout to loop/run after a function is called to automatically update/refresh a div.

**What Isn't Working:**
To be clear settimeout is working, but the div is not automatically refreshing/updating when I enter new test data into the db. In other words, If I refresh the page, I see the new test data, but not if I let the update function run.

**Code:**

```
function update(a) {
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "core/engine.php",   
    data: "q=data&account="+a,          
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        if(response=="nologin") {
            alert("Sorry, but either your account is not activated or your login is incorrect!");
        } else {
            console.log("Queried Database...");
            var j = $.parseJSON(response);
            $.each(j, function (k, v) {
                    $("#login-box").hide();
                    //$("#trades").html(' ');
                    localStorage.setItem("wings_lastsignal", v.candel);
                    var lastsignal = localStorage.getItem("wings_lastsignal");
                    console.log(v.candel);
                    if(lastsignal == v.candel) {
                        console.log("No New Signals");
                        localStorage.getItem("wings_currentsignals");
                        if(v.signal == 'Buy') {
                        console.log("Current Buy Sent...");

                    $("#trades").append('<span id="'+v.candel+'" class="tradesignal"><span class="signalarrowup"></span>'+v.time+'<span style="color:#2DC14E;"> '+v.signal+'</span> &ensp; <button class="tsym" id="sym_'+v.epoch+'" onClick="var a = this.innerHTML; tsclick(a);" value="'+v.symbol+'">'+v.symbol+'</button>&ensp; '+v.price+'&ensp; '+v.timeframe+'</span>'); 
                } else {
                    console.log("Current Sell Sent...");

                    $("#trades").append('<span id="'+v.candel+'" class="tradesignal"><span class="signalarrowdown"></span>'+v.time+'<span style="color:#fb5350;"> '+v.signal+'</span> &ensp; <button class="tsym" id="sym_'+v.epoch+'">'+v.symbol+'</button>&ensp; '+v.price+'&ensp; '+v.timeframe+'</span>'); 
                }

                    } else {
                    playChing();
                    console.log("New Signal");
                    if(v.signal == 'Buy') {
                        console.log("Buy Sent...");

                    $("#trades").append('<span id="'+v.candel+'" class="tradesignal"><span class="signalarrowup"></span>'+v.time+'<span style="color:#2DC14E;"> '+v.signal+'</span> &ensp; <button class="tsym" id="sym_'+v.epoch+'" onClick="var a = this.innerHTML; tsclick(a);" value="'+v.symbol+'">'+v.symbol+'</button>&ensp; '+v.price+'&ensp; '+v.timeframe+'</span>'); 
                } else {
                    console.log("Sell Sent...");

                    $("#trades").append('<span id="'+v.candel+'" class="tradesignal"><span class="signalarrowdown"></span>'+v.time+'<span style="color:#fb5350;"> '+v.signal+'</span> &ensp; <button class="tsym" id="sym_'+v.epoch+'">'+v.symbol+'</button>&ensp; '+v.price+'&ensp; '+v.timeframe+'</span>'); 
                }
                }

            });
        }   
        //alert(response);
        //console.log(response);
    }

}).then(function() {         // on completion, restart
   var a = localStorage.getItem("wingsaccnum");
   //setTimeout(update, 10000);
   setTimeout(function(){ update(a) }, 20000);  // function refers to itself
   console.log("Timeout");

});
}
```

This function is called when I a button is pressed, using this Jquery snippet:

```
 $( "#rbuttonon" ).click(function() {
var acc = localStorage.getItem("wingsaccnum");
//refresh_box();
update(acc);
console.log('Interval set');
 });
```

**Other Notes:**
To be clear, I don't mind if there is a way to always make sure this div is updated every xx amount of time, without the need to press any buttons. I believe the problem is in my code's logic, but I would greatly appreciate some assistance!

Comment: Is the update function being called, if so do you see all the appropriate console prints that you have in your code?

Comment: It seems to be getting called. I am basically only seeing console prints for the portion of the code where there are no new signals.

Comment: Even if I know there is a new test data entered into the database, the code doesn't seem to detect it, which makes me believe the problem is in my logic.

Comment: Well my goal was to record the current signals when the page loads. Then check last signal against the incoming data upon the function loading. In my head, this should mean that if the candel value changes then a new signal should get recorded. If the candel value doesn't change, then it should just load the currentsignals that were already given. Please feel free to chat me, and I can give you a link

Comment: Swap those two calls around

Comment: So say if(v.candel == lastcandel) or say if(lastsignal != v.candel) Heinrich?

Comment: localStorage.setItem("wings_lastsignal", v.candel);
var lastsignal = localStorage.getItem("wings_lastsignal"); swap these two lines

Comment: Now its only logging everything as a new signal. Even signals that were already there. I basically am just trying to get it to auto update the div so that it shows fresh data, and get it to play a sound every time something new appears. But not play a sound when only old stuff is there.

Comment: Its still not updating the div with any new data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128305/discussion-between-heinrich-and-user3259138).